# Clickjacking through X-Frame in Worklight 7.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am using MFP 7.0. I would like to protect my desktop browser app from Clickjacking through X-Frame. Is there some configuration to be made in the server which can add the X-Frame option to the response header?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This feature is available in MFP 7.0. Use any of the iFixes later than September 2015 to get the feature.

Once you have the iFix installed, you can configure your desktop browser environment or mobile web app environment to prevent clickjacking through X-Frames.

The configuration in your application-descriptor.xml will be:

```
<mobileWebApp cacheManifest="no-use" xFrameOptions="DENY"/>
<desktopBrowser cacheManifest="no-use" xFrameOptions="DENY"/>
```

The other options available are :

> no-use

OR

> SAMEORIGIN

More details [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI43682).